# Setting up Classpath

Tags: java, classpath

I'm new to Java and trying to get to grips with setting up Classpath. Do I have to set a new classpath for each class file I want to run? Do I have to set it to the exact directory where the class file is or a directory containing that class file?

Comment: The official (and free) documentation answers  all that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: You should never, ever set a CLASSPATH environment variable.  Never, ever.  Yes you have to tell the application where to find each and every class that it needs to load.  You should do that using the -classpath argument at compile and runtime.

Comment: The -classpath argument doesn't seem to work. I'm getting could not find or load main class [-classpath]. When I try it without the brackets it just returns the help for java.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, right-click on Computer -> Properties -> Advanced system settings; then in the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables... -> System variables -> New....

Give the new system variable the name JAVA_HOME and the value value C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 (depending on your JDK installation path it varies).

Then select the Path system variable and click Edit.... Keep the variable name as Path, and append C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin; or %JAVA_HOME%\bin; (both mean the same) to the variable value.

If there are any issues executing programs, try these steps. If you don't see similar results, you may need to reinstall JDK.

Open a Windows command prompt (Windows key + R -> enter cmd -> OK), and check the following:

java -version

You will see something like this:

java version "1.7.0_79" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Then check the following:

javac -version

You will see something like this:

javac 1.7.0_79

If you are new to java start with some ide like eclipse or idea as there the classpath settings are not required generally . And also java tries to find the classpath by Looking at your directory.

> And class path is set for java as a whole  not for a project or class
>   file. Once set it can be used by n number of java classes